# How to assign additional properties with one property in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a Angular service and in it I have variables like this:

```js
export class MyService {

  someVariableA = 1;

  someParams = {
    someVariableB,
    otherVariable: this.someVariableA
  };
}
```

and in a component I set the 'someVariableA' to 3

> this.myService.someVariableA = 3;

and I want 'otherVariable' to get that value 3 as well, but it doesn't. It remains 1 when I go to get the value.

> let v = this.myService.someParams.otherVariable;

Is it possible to set 'otherVariable' this way or any other way via 'someVariableA'?

Comment: You can do [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?useDefineForClassFields=true#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBlApgJwG4EtjOgbwChpjoATZUMVXCAewFtkA1KzMAIxGQEEAuaAHYBXeuzQBuIiXKVq0OowAKVMPQj9CJLfIbNWHLgCF+w0RKnbotAC4ALNC1RtOyEyLGpJWgL5eSwWgEIa1QhYGtaVAAKAEp8C207TAgAOgU9JwMeaABeaABGP0sAoOtoOzAyvKSIIsTbZLTdZVRVGDzNS210x2cjfgAmABoErugAc2Qym3tUXqzY+LGx6mshVAFy20qmxnmXblGu7xHlkggpqzsHfRco9DAQNzNUOM6zrQrrXYy+7LyHiA6mNvEdiKCfARQSVgtA1LlBMgAO5wJBoLA4WKSNQ-fZcbgI-IABiJkhhtC4KRAtHGURx6RabRSMxumRcMXE0AA9FyCiSCPTmiocSy5rcuAiALQAVjJgTolOptMFe3FPA53N5MqAA); do you want me to write up an answer?

Comment: cool! I see your example. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Zulwarnain answered, 1 is a number or a primitive data type. Primitive data types in javascript are passed by value, not by reference which you seem to be expecting here.

An easy fix for this is to assign a function to otherVariable instead. Now just invoke the function someParams.otherVariable() and it will return the value of someVariableA. No need to make this complicated.

```js
export class SingletonService {
  public someVariableA = 1;

  public someParams = {
    otherVariable: () => this.someVariableA
  };
}
```

This is basic javascript with multiple sources covering the subject.

https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

Comment: I like this answer

Comment: Short and nice solution. For non break change on client side, a getter instead of a function would do the trick also (see jcalz answer)

Answer (score 2):

I concur with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60022409/2887218) that you will have a better time if you use a reference type like an object/array instead of a primitive value type like a number.  By adding one layer of indirection (e.g., `someVar = 123` becomes `someVar = {value: 123}`) you could very easily get similar functionality to what you're seeking.

If, however, your use case *requires* an object's property to directly act like a reference to a primitive value type stored somewhere else, you can get this behavior by implementing the property as a [getter and setter pair](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters).  It's more complicated, but it acts the way you want.

Here's an example:

```
class MyService {
    someVariableA = 1;
    someParams: {
        someVariableB: number;
        otherVariable: number;
    };
    constructor() {
        this.someVariableA = 1;
        const that = this;
        this.someParams = {
            someVariableB: 2,
            get otherVariable() {
                return that.someVariableA
            },
            set otherVariable(val: number) {
                that.someVariableA = val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in order for the `otherVariable` getter and setter to be able to access the right context, I had to move the code into the constructor and copy `this` into a new variable I called `that`.  The `this` context of a getter/setter refers to the object it's a member of, and not some `this` from an outer scope.

Let's make sure it works:

```
const ms = new MyService();
ms.someVariableA = 100;
console.log(ms.someParams.otherVariable); // 100
ms.someParams.otherVariable = -5;
console.log(ms.someVariableA); // -5
```

Looks good; changes to `ms.someVariableA` are immediately reflected in `ms.someParams.otherVariable`, and vice versa.  All right, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBlApgJwG4EtjOgb2gChoToIB7AW2QDUxVMwAjEZAQWgF5oBGAbmKkK1AAr0wlCAC58g0kKq16jFsgBCMgHYBXSkzQD588gBcAFmjoNmrLbv2pDpAL5OSwcpognU24CfJUAAoASlkjUnNMCAA6YSVrVQ5ufjkjDy8TaHMwLO4oiDcjArjFMVQJGG48NIiSeKsVVg1oACYAGlq6gHNkLNMLVEabZFDwuonUPu1UTWyzXNLqYaSuiOdOifkIPugBy2URoPQwEDs9NDCarbqckyWEpvYuaBOQIonnNegv+S+vjLeaCSF6aZAAdzgSDQWBwoQEkgeK1YyV4AAY0QJAeRWDEQORukFEfFypUYvshodVCE+NAAPR09FowjEsriREU5G4bgAWgArFjPBRcfjCazllSUTT6Yz+UA)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the **value type** this will not work like you want. you need to assign **reference type**

```
obj ={someVariableA : 1};

  someParams = {
    otherVariable: this.obj
  };
```

in the above code, if you change the value of obj.someVariableA it will also change the value of someParams.otherVariable

> I am expexting that you have knowledge about reference type and value types variables

[click here for demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-referencetype-variable?file=app/hello.component.ts)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you want to do that. I believe you are getting a new instance of the service each time you call it, so the variables get reset.

you might want to set that variable in localStorage instead, and then have the service retrieve it from localStorage. That way it will always be getting whatever it was last set to.

or just pass that variable into your service call, instead of trying to use a local service variable.

Comment: Not true. I can set variables in my service and call them at different times from different components (.ts file) and the values persist.

Comment: oh ok, well what you have above is setting otherVariable to whatever value is currently in someVariableA. not a reference to someVariableA. so changing someVariableA is not going to change otherVariable.

Comment: why not just access someVariableA? not sure why you would want to have 2 different variable names for the same value. seems like trouble.

Comment: because I have multiple objects in that service ex. someParams1, someParams2, etc They all have different properties except 'someVariableA' which they all share. Now, in my components I pass around 'someParams1' and 'someParams2'